# 'Clipbrd' in Delphi is corrupt

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-2009

When using the unit `Clipbrd`, anyone know of text corruption that happens?

After accessing bitmap

```
    bitmap.Assign(Clipboard);
```

Text from the clipboard seems to be corrupted. With English it works fine, however it shifts to strange characters such as
`ã`

Is this an "open bug"?

Is there a way to handle this and return the clipboard to its normal operations without restarting the computer?

#### The code

```
Clipboard.Open;
bitmap.Assign(Clipboard);
Clipboard.Close;
```

Results in the same results.

My guess is it goes to somewhere with encoding.

Their corruption of the clipboard is for user experience outside the software. The clipboard become non useable for non-English languages.

After any the extraction of a pic, the clipboard cannot transfer non-English even after Delphi is shut down, or the software.

I am testing with:

> 大日本帝國

Copy and paste result:

```
?????

unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Clipbrd, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    img1: TImage;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
bitmap : TBitmap;
begin
  bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  bitmap.Assign(Clipboard);
  img1.picture.Assign(bitmap);
  FreeAndNil(bitmap);
end;

end.
```

dfm :

```
object Form4: TForm4
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form4'
  ClientHeight = 282
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object img1: TImage
    Left = 168
    Top = 64
    Width = 105
    Height = 105
  end
  object btn1: TButton
    Left = 184
    Top = 232
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'btn1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btn1Click
  end
end
```

- Compile and execute.
- Go to start → *Run*
- Then type in (do not copy from here!)

> יגדכלחילדגחכי

Then paste back, and you would get

> éâãëìçéìãâçëé

Comment: Have you tried Clipboard.Clear; or combination of Clipboard.Open; / Clipboard.Close; ?

Comment: if the user wants to use the clipboard for its own use, the the first time he gets a~ then he gets only ? there is a transformation the text goes which is unclear.

Comment: Show complete program and instructions to allow reproduction of problem. Otherwise this is a non-question.

Comment: What does `start->Run` have to do with anything? If you're trying to assign a bitmap the contents of the clipboard,  then you need to have an image in the clipboard in the first place. If you're putting text in the clipboard, then you should be retrieving it as text into a container (label, edit, etc.) that is meant to contain text.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `TClipboard` object to `TBitmap.Assign()` will only read from the clipboard. It will not write anything to the clipboard or otherwise alter the contents of the clipboard in any way.

So the problem is not in the code you showed. The only possibility I can think of right now is that whichever application stored the bitmap on the clipboard in the first place likely stored it with delay rendering enabled, and it is updating the clipboard the wrong way when storing the now-rendered bitmap when `TBitmap.Assigns()` asks the clipboard for it.

Comment: The bitmap is stored with printscreen. did you try to reproduce the bug?